# A formula that guarantees that f(ULLONG_MAX) * f(ULLONG_MAX) is not more than ULLONG_MAX

Tags: c++

I'm making a container class and I want to specify that its maximum size, if multiplied by itself, should not be more than the maximum value of `unsigned long long` (specifically, `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`).

Assuming that `ULLONG_MAX` is **2<sup>64</sup>-1**, how safe is this calculation and how can I improve it if necessary?

```cpp
typedef unsigned long long size_type;
size_type max_size = size_type(std::sqrt(ULLONG_MAX)) - 1;
```

Comment: Although not formally guaranteed by the (C++11 and later) standards .....   Practically, if `ULLONG_MAX` is 2^64-1,  it is usually true that `ULONG_MAX`  (aka `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()`) is 2^32-1.    That value, squared does not exceed 2^64-1 (but add one and square it, and it does).

Comment: I'd also query using `unsigned long long` for indices or to represent the maximum size of a container.   The standard library uses `std::size_t` for exactly that purpose, and the size/range of that type tends to be the maximum suitable for the target platform.

Comment: @Peter "*if `ULLONG_MAX` is 2^64-1,  it is usually true that `ULONG_MAX` ... is 2^32-1*" - that is only true when `long` is 32bit, but it is 64bit on some platforms.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -   On platforms where `long` is 64 bit,  `long long` is typically (well) longer.

Comment: @Peter I don't know of any platform where `long long` is larger (ie 128-bit) than `long`. The standard only guarantees that `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`, so they can be the same.

Comment: That's where you use `std::uint32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

2<sup>32</sup> squared is 2<sup>64</sup>, too big.

2<sup>32</sup> - 1 squared is 2<sup>64</sup>-2<sup>33</sup>+1.

So just use 2<sup>32</sup>-1.

In general `(static_cast<T>(1) << static_cast<T>(sizeof(T)*4)) - 1` gets you the largest squarable unsigned value of type `T`, if `T` is an unsigned integral type.

Comment: Shouldn't the shift be in parentheses?

Comment: @rusan yes.  * before +, everything else use ()